# Problem about metric spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite set and let $d$ be the discrete metric on $X$. What sets in $X$ are open? Closed? Compact?

Now, I know that $d$ will be either $0$ or $1$ since we are talking about the discrete metric. So, does this mean that no matter how many elements are in $X$, the set will only contain $0$ and $1$? I am having trouble grasping the concept of sets on the discrete metric and how to proceed with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Try to understand whether or not singletons are open, closed.

Comment: Singletons have no limit points right?

Comment: More explicit hint: For any point $x \in X$, the ball with radius $1/2$ centered at $x$ under the discrete metric is $B(x,1/2)=\{x\}$. So you are right, a sequence cannot converge to a point unless it is eventually equal to that point after some term. This hint also shows that any singleton, being a basic open set of the topology induced by the discrete metric, is open.

Comment: So, all singletons in this set $X$ are open sets, but do there exist any closed sets? Also, these singletons are not compact since they are not closed.

Comment: Singletons are open, therefore all possible unions of singletons are open. But wait... All possible unions of singletons give you all subsets of $X$, which means that all subsets of $X$ are open. But then, since closed sets are complements of open sets, all subsets of $X$ are also closed. For compactness, you should follow the hints in Paul's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Any subset of $X$ is closed and open, since $X$ is discrete.

And and finite subset of $X$ is compact.

Any infinite subset $A$ of $X$ is not compact.

**Proof:**  $\{x\}_{x\in A}$ is a covering of $X$, however it hasn't finite subcovering.

Comment: Why is any finite subset compact?

Comment: Notice that every point of discrete space is **open**. Then use the definition of compactness.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Whenever you are given a metric, it is always useful to ask yourself what does an open ball look like?
Fix $a \in X$ and let $r > 0$. Then

$B(a,r) = \{ x \in X| d(a,x) \leq r \}$

$d(a,a) = 0$ and $d(a, x) = 1$ whenever $a \neq x$. If $0 \leq r \leq 1$, then $B(a, r) = \{a \}$. If $r > 1$, then $B(a, r) = X$.